# Why does Export-Csv prompt me for an InputObject

Tags: powershell, csv

First of all, here's the script I wrote so far:

```
Get-Mailbox | Select-Object Name, Alias, ServerName
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} | FT samAccountName, Surname,     Enabled

Export-Csv c:\UA.csv -Delimiter " " -NoTypeInformation
```

The output basically shows 2 rows of results (Name, Alias and ServerName list above and samAccountName, Surname and Enabled list below). However, below the output it asks me for an InputObject, so clearly the Export-Csv didn't work.

```
cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject:
```

Am I doing something wrong? I'm a beginner in PowerShell and scripting in general. Thanks in advance.

EDIT (Clarification):
The output I am aiming for is one clear table in Excel with all the properties (Name, Alias, Enabled etc.) in a list with separate columns. So far with the help below I have managed to get half of it working.

Comment: The data you gather from `Get-Mailbox` and `Get-ADUser` isn’t assigned to any variable and as such lost. Depending on the actual shell behavior, you may see their output. But that output is not fed to `Export-Csv` or anything the like.

Comment: I'm guessing that's what Kage below tried to rectify with his version of the script, correct? I sort of understand the concept now. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Perhaps you should manually create one or two lines of how the output is supposed to look like and [include that in your question](http://superuser.com/posts/1116643/edit).

Comment: Hope I clarified it enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = @()
$mailboxes = Get-mailbox
$exportto = "H:\Export.csv"
 foreach($mailbox in $mailboxes)
 {
    $user = Get-ADUser $mailbox.SAMAccountName -Properties Displayname
    if(!$user.Enabled)
    {
        $result += $Mailbox.DisplayName + "," + $mailbox.Alias + "," + $mailbox.ServerName + "," + $user.Samaccountname + "," + $user.Surname + "," + $user.Enabled | Out-file $exportto -Append
    }
 }
```

I think this would do what you want it to do.
First it will get all the mailboxes, then for every mailbox it finds it will run a get-aduser and only for the disabled users it will put it in the combined list.

Edit---- : (the more efficient way)

```
$exportto = "H:\Export.csv"

foreach($user in Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false})
{
    $mailbox = Get-Mailbox $user.SamAccountName
    $Mailbox.DisplayName + "," + $mailbox.Alias + "," + $mailbox.ServerName + "," + $user.Samaccountname + "," + $user.Surname + "," + $user.Enabled | Out-file $exportto -Append
}
```

Comment: #TYPE System.String
"Length"
"44"
"183"
<- Unfortunately this is the output .csv file. PS doesn't show any warnings. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Ok lets try this again :)  see the edit

Comment: Well the output is completely different, that's for sure. There are 6 columns which is a good start. From left to right they're called "DarkRoom, DarkRoom, test-ex103, DarkRoom, (Empty), FALSE. Unfortunately didn't work again, and I don't have time to look at it again today, I'll probably get back to it tomorrow. Thanks for the efforts btw :)

Comment: It should show the Displayname,Exchange Alias, Exchange Server, AD Username, Surname, Enabled

Comment: I know, the idea is correct I see what you tried to achieve. Unfortunately it didn't work out, but like I said I'll take another look at it tomorrow and get back at you.

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do, however bassicly the command Export-CSV does not have anything to export for you.
This is how it could work:

```
Get-Mailbox | Select-Object Name,Alias,Servername | Export-csv Filepath\filename.csv -NoTypeInformation
Get-AdUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} | Select-Object samAccountName,Surname| Export-csv Filepath\filename.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Or

```
$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox | Select-Object Name,Alias,Servername 
$Users = Get-AdUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} | Select-Object samAccountName,Surname

$mailboxes | Export-csv Filepath\filename.csv  -NoTypeInformation
$users | Export-csv Filepath\filename.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This way you bassicly pass the results from the commands to the Export csv command.
FYI you can use "epcsv"  instead of Export-CSV its a short command for it.
FYI2  When using this way you cannot use ft (Format-Table) when you do that you get gibberish in your export, this is the same when using fl (Format-List). thus i changed it to Select-Object

If this was not exactly what you were looking for please make your question clearer :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is quite simple, I want to export the data (lists) that I get from the Get-Mailbox and Get-ADUser to excel as a .csv file so that I am able to create a table from the data. I tried both scripts, (Thanks a lot for the suggestions btw) and unfortunately the output was the following: samAccountName "Surname" "Enabled"
$051000-N6NRHJCL553M  "False"
NotToBeUsed  "False"
The whole output is too long, but it's not the clear text list that comes up normally. Still, thanks for the effort :)

Comment: I would suggest not changing the Delimiter(so removing the parameter) and when you open it in excel using the text to column function. It should work. Also as additional question. in the results it now lists Enabled, this is actually not needed since u know all the accounts which are returned in the list are disabled due to the filter in the command, so the enabled part u ccould remove all together.  See the edits i just made.

Comment: Yes, I managed to get half of the script working thanks to your help (And on the old script I simply added a , to the delimiter). I did the text to column import to excel and I get the correct and full table of the samAccountname, Surname and Enabled (Necessary or not, I prefer to keep "Enabled" there). Now the strange thing is it won't show the first 3 options, Name, Alias and Servername. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Thats because thats a different command and different output. if you want it all in one list thats a different command which i think should be possible but i would need to try it out

Comment: That would be very kind.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple as Kage suggested. You are missing the Delimiter before Export and because of this the export is taken as a standalone command but there is nothing to export. Try it like this:

```
    Get-Mailbox | Select-Object Name, Alias, ServerName
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} | FT samAccountName, Surname,     Enabled | Export-Csv c:\UA.csv -Delimiter " " -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
Get-Mailbox | Select-Object Name, Alias, ServerName
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} | FT samAccountName, Surname,     Enabled **|**

Export-Csv c:\UA.csv -Delimiter " " -NoTypeInformation
```